# Convert Javascript object to a JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I want to directly convert a javascript object to string. I used following code.

```
var foo = {};  
foo.test1 = test1;  
foo.test2 = test2;  
foo.test3 = test3;  

var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(foo);
```

It works fine but it uses the json2 javascript library. However I need to do this in plain javascript without using any libraries. I know creating the json feed using passed parameters will work like this.

```
var jsonObj = "{\"test1\":\"" + test1+ "\",\"test2\":\"" + test2+ "\",\"test3\":\"" + test3+ "\"}";
```

However if the passed parameters(test1, test2 and test3) contains double quotes it will have issues.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you use a library? Especially one as small and special purposed as json2.js.

Comment: Indeed, you could even stick a minified version of json2.js in along with your other code, you don't have to keep it in a separate file.

Comment: You don't need to include json2.js if you aren't planning on supporting very old browsers (or browsers built like its still 2001).

Comment: I dont want to use this im dealing with a server side javascript library like node.js. Hence its essential to omit this kind of third party libraries.

Comment: @Dilshan: if it's server-side JS, there's a good chance the implementation supports `JSON.stringify` natively.  node.js does.

Comment: Thanks. But this is bit different from that. This is a library we are currently developing on. Still it doesnt have that support. However thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the double quotes by performing a `String.replace(/"/g, "\\\"")` on each key and member. For this to work however, you need to guarantee that you will only have simple strings/ numbers in your JS object.

FYI, it should be noted that the `json2` library will only be used when a native implementation of JSON does not exist; [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=json) have JSON support build in (IE < 8 is the noticable exception).

Comment: Will fail if the string includes a new line

Comment: Why are you escaping the double quotes in the regular expression? They don't have any special meaning there so that just adds line noise.

Comment: @Quentin: Because it was a string before and I forgot to remove it when I changed it to a regular expression ;)

Comment: Yes replacing this is fine. But I needed a better way of doing this. Isnt there any straight forward approach to convert directly like that json2 library function? I tried to use JSON.stringifyin my server side javascript and simply it failed. Im using latest firefox version.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've totally misunderstood what JSON is. JSON Stands for Javascript Object Notation.

What you haven't realised is that `foo` is already an object and further have you actually thought about what you'd be coding to access `jsonObj` ?

Here's a hint `jsonObj.test1` : looks familiar doesn't it.

What you might be trying to do is to create a string that looks like JSON content but isn't in fact an object. That's a different question though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes Im trying to create a string like json

Comment: so can I assume that you will *not* be using `jsonObj` like an object? You will be just printing it to screen or something?

Comment: Then you don't need to do any conversion at all! A string and an object are not the same thing. If you read my answer you would have realsed that `foo === jsonObj` you do not need to even create `jsonObj` because you can read properties directly from `foo`. But if you really must, then all you needed to do was `var jsonObj = foo;` then you could happily read the same properties without all that string nonsense.